# In SQL SERVER 2008 part of heder data is occuring agin in the CSV file generated

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

Problem: In SQL SERVER 2008 part of heder data is occuring agin in the CSV file generated using BCP command. Table.columnname is part of header and we have 3000 columns to be extracted.
Header length is 176,000 character. So on running BCP command file generated contains

Header(fine)
Data(no issues)
Some part of header occuring maliciously in the CSV file(this is the issue as some part of header starting from any character and ending at any character)

Example of CSV:
tabl1.col1,tabl2.col1.......tablen.coln
1,2,dd,g,g,
3,4,hghh,hjjj
table20.col10,tabl20.col1.....so on (substring of header repetition)

Note: we are extracting data using BCP command from a temporary table having 22 columns of nvarchar(max) data type and header length is 176,000 char